# How to call Google Big Query non-legacy SQL using Google App Script?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use Google App Scripts to trigger a Google Big Query query as per the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#reference

Since my query uses the new DML functionality it needs to use non-legacy SQL.

Is this possible using Google App Script? How do I specify non-legacy SQL?

Comment: I'll have to come back to this - I'm not sure which answer to select as I've encountered a different problem. Posting elsewhere as I suspect it's un-related.

Comment: Ah, got there sooner than expected. Truth be told I couldn't get Mijhail's and Pentium10's solutions to worked, but not 100% sure I implemented as intended. Elliott's answer has now worked for me. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: Can anyone volunteer whether this is an advisable way to automate GBQ queries? I've come across Google's CLI, but this so far seems easier. Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you need to use `#StandardSQL` in the query text. Using the sample code on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#reference as a reference, it should be sufficient to change:

```
var request = {
  query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' +
    'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'
};
```

to:

```
var request = {
  query: 'SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' +
    'FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare` WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;',
  useLegacySql = false
};
```

Specifically, you need to add the `useLegacySql` key to the request.

Comment: it's actually `useLegacySql : false` instead of `useLegacySql = false` but many thanks it saved me a lot of times

Answer (score 3):

Very Minor correction in the accepted answer. (Semicolon needed, not equals symbol)

It should be

useLegacySql : false

And not

useLegacySql = false

Comment: this can be a comment to that answer actually

Comment: I had tried that initially but I don't have enough points of reputation to comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to enforce Standard SQL without code change.
Just make sure that the first line of your query is

```
#StandardSQL
```

and BigQuery will treat the rest of the query as Standard SQL

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your first line of your query is

```
#StandardSQL
select 1;
```